# Why cant I combine these two scripts

Tags: php, scripting, upload

I have these two scripts. One is an mysql `INSERT INTO` a `DATABASE`.

The second created a new directory and uploads upto 5 images into the newly created folder.

They both work as seperate entities but when i try and combine them it will not insert the information into the database. There must be something conflicting that I just cant see.

Here is the upload files code that works:

```
<?php



// Assigning $_POSTS to variables


//login details

$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];
$password_entry = $_POST['password_entry'];

//!login details

//contact details

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$address3 = $_POST['address3'];
$address4 = $_POST['address4'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
$whatareyou = $_POST['whatareyou'];
$business_description = $_POST['business_description'];
$website = $_POST['website'];

//!contact details

//opening times

$opening_monday_from = $_POST ['opening_monday_from'];
$opening_monday_to = $_POST ['opening_monday_to'];

$opening_tuesday_from = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_from'];
$opening_tuesday_to = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_to'];

$opening_wednesday_from = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_from'];
$opening_wednesday_to = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_to'];

$opening_thursday_from = $_POST ['opening_thursday_from'];
$opening_thursday_to = $_POST ['opening_thursday_to'];

$opening_friday_from = $_POST ['opening_friday_from'];
$opening_friday_to = $_POST ['opening_friday_to'];

$opening_saturday_from = $_POST ['opening_saturday_from'];
$opening_saturday_to = $_POST ['opening_saturday_to'];

$opening_sunday_from = $_POST ['opening_sunday_from'];
$opening_sunday_to = $_POST ['opening_sunday_to'];



//!opening times


// !Assigning $_POSTS to varaiables

// DataBase credentials

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'welcometowarwick';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

//! DataBase credentials

// Connect to DataBase

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link, 
   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db,
   $port
);

//! Connect to DataBase


$directoryPath = "user_images/".$username_entry;
mkdir($directoryPath, 0777, true);



if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
  $files = $_FILES['upload'];

  for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {
    $name = $files['name'][$x];
    $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "user_images/{$username_entry}/{$name}");

  //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>';

    $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]);
    $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]);
    $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]);
    $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]);
    $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]);

  }


  $insert_upload1 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload1";
  $insert_upload2 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload2";
  $insert_upload3 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload3";
  $insert_upload4 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload4";
  $insert_upload5 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload5";

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);


  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ofnissenisub321 (timestamp, username, password, business_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, email, website, Facebook, twitter, linkedin, opening_monday_from, opening_monday_to, opening_tuesday_from, opening_tuesday_to, opening_wednesday_from, opening_wednesday_to, opening_thursday_from, opening_friday_from, opening_friday_to, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_to, opening_sunday_from, opening_sunday_to, business_type, business_description, managers_message, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5) VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password_entry'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['postcode'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['website'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['facebook'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['twitter'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['linkedin'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['managers_message'], "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload1, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload2, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload3, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload4, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload5, "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_w2w, $w2w);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $w2w) or die(mysql_error());  }






if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

//! MySQLi insertInto
?> 


?>
```

And here is the INSERT code, again, works:

```
<?php



// Assigning $_POSTS to variables


//login details

$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];
$password_entry = $_POST['password_entry'];

//!login details

//contact details

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$address3 = $_POST['address3'];
$address4 = $_POST['address4'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
$whatareyou = $_POST['whatareyou'];
$business_description = $_POST['business_description'];
$website = $_POST['website'];

//!contact details

//opening times

$opening_monday_from = $_POST ['opening_monday_from'];
$opening_monday_to = $_POST ['opening_monday_to'];

$opening_tuesday_from = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_from'];
$opening_tuesday_to = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_to'];

$opening_wednesday_from = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_from'];
$opening_wednesday_to = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_to'];

$opening_thursday_from = $_POST ['opening_thursday_from'];
$opening_thursday_to = $_POST ['opening_thursday_to'];

$opening_friday_from = $_POST ['opening_friday_from'];
$opening_friday_to = $_POST ['opening_friday_to'];

$opening_saturday_from = $_POST ['opening_saturday_from'];
$opening_saturday_to = $_POST ['opening_saturday_to'];

$opening_sunday_from = $_POST ['opening_sunday_from'];
$opening_sunday_to = $_POST ['opening_sunday_to'];



//!opening times


// !Assigning $_POSTS to varaiables

// DataBase credentials

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'welcometowarwick';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

//! DataBase credentials

// Connect to DataBase

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link, 
   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db,
   $port
);

//! Connect to DataBase





//MySQLi insertInto

$sql = "INSERT INTO business_info 
(
username,
password,
email,
email2,
tel,
address1,
address2,
address3,
address4,
postcode,
facebook,
twitter,
opening_monday_to,
opening_monday_from,
opening_tuesday_to,
opening_tuesday_from,
opening_wednesday_to,
opening_wednesday_from,
opening_thursday_to,
opening_thursday_from,
opening_friday_to,
opening_friday_from,
opening_saturday_to,
opening_saturday_from,
opening_sunday_to,
opening_sunday_from,
whatareyou,
business_description,
image1,
image2,
image3,
image4,
image5,
website


) 
VALUES 
(
'$username_entry',
'$password_entry',
'$email1',
'$email2',
'$tel', 
'$address1',
'$address2',
'$address3',
'$address4',
'$postcode',
'$facebook',
'$twitter',
'$opening_monday_to',
'$opening_monday_from',
'$opening_tuesday_to',
'$opening_tuesday_from',
'$opening_wednesday_to',
'$opening_wednesday_from',
'$opening_thursday_to',
'$opening_thursday_from',
'$opening_friday_to',
'$opening_friday_from',
'$opening_saturday_to',
'$opening_saturday_from',
'$opening_sunday_to',
'$opening_sunday_from',
'$whatareyou',
'$business_description',
'$image1',
'$image2',
'$image3',
'$image4',
'$image5',
'$website'
)";



if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

//! MySQLi insertInto
?>
```

I have tried different combinations of these two codes (which is why there are irrelevent bits in the `UPLOAD` script. However both just tested seperately and both do the jobs required. I just cant get them to both run at the same time.

Can anyone shed some light on this please. Thanks :)

Basically I just want to add the mkdir upload script into the `INSERT` script without disrupting it....

******EDIT HERE IS THE SCRIPT I CANNOT MAKE WORK******

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Assigning $_POSTS to variables


//login details

$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];
$password_entry = $_POST['password_entry'];

//!login details

//contact details

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$address3 = $_POST['address3'];
$address4 = $_POST['address4'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
$whatareyou = $_POST['whatareyou'];
$business_description = $_POST['business_description'];
$website = $_POST['website'];

//!contact details

//opening times

$opening_monday_from = $_POST ['opening_monday_from'];
$opening_monday_to = $_POST ['opening_monday_to'];

$opening_tuesday_from = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_from'];
$opening_tuesday_to = $_POST ['opening_tuesday_to'];

$opening_wednesday_from = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_from'];
$opening_wednesday_to = $_POST ['opening_wednesday_to'];

$opening_thursday_from = $_POST ['opening_thursday_from'];
$opening_thursday_to = $_POST ['opening_thursday_to'];

$opening_friday_from = $_POST ['opening_friday_from'];
$opening_friday_to = $_POST ['opening_friday_to'];

$opening_saturday_from = $_POST ['opening_saturday_from'];
$opening_saturday_to = $_POST ['opening_saturday_to'];

$opening_sunday_from = $_POST ['opening_sunday_from'];
$opening_sunday_to = $_POST ['opening_sunday_to'];



//!opening times


// !Assigning $_POSTS to varaiables

// DataBase credentials

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'welcometowarwick';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

//! DataBase credentials

// Connect to DataBase

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link, 
   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db,
   $port
);

//! Connect to DataBase


$directoryPath = "user_images/".$username_entry;

mkdir($directoryPath, 0777, true);



if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
  $files = $_FILES['upload'];

  for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {
    $name = $files['name'][$x];
    $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "user_images/{$username_entry}/{$name}");

  //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>';

    $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]);
    $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]);
    $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]);
    $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]);
    $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]);

  }


  $insert_upload1 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload1";
  $insert_upload2 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload2";
  $insert_upload3 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload3";
  $insert_upload4 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload4";
  $insert_upload5 = "user_images/$username_entry/$image_upload5";

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);


  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ofnissenisub321 (timestamp, username, password, business_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, email, website, Facebook, twitter, linkedin, opening_monday_from, opening_monday_to, opening_tuesday_from, opening_tuesday_to, opening_wednesday_from, opening_wednesday_to, opening_thursday_from, opening_friday_from, opening_friday_to, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_to, opening_sunday_from, opening_sunday_to, business_type, business_description, managers_message, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5) VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password_entry'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['postcode'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['website'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['facebook'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['twitter'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['linkedin'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_from'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_to'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['managers_message'], "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload1, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload2, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload3, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload4, "text"),
             GetSQLValueString($insert_upload5, "text"));

  mysql_select_db($success, $insertSQL);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $link) or die(mysql_error());  }






if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

//! MySQLi insertInto
?> 


?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your combined? Were there any errors?

Comment: Essentially, it is the UPLOAD script, it has all the vars set and and all the inserts in it, but it just wont work when using in conjunction with the mkdir and upload. I added the INSERT by itself to show that that works fine, although it is slightly different, I cant see why it wouldnt work...It just shows a blank screen. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as clean as i want, but i suggest you to try this rewrite of your code :

```
<?php 

// Comment in production
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// DataBase credentials & connection
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'welcometowarwick';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;


$link = mysqli_connect(
    $host,
    $user,
    $password,
    $db,
    $port
);


if (!$link) {
    die('DB connection error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($link, $db);



## Functions


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
        global $link;

        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}



$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];

if (empty($_POST['username_entry'])) {
    die('Username must be given');
}

$user_image_dir = "user_images";


mkdir($user_image_dir."/".$username_entry, 0777, true);


if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload']; 

    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) { 
        $name = $files['name'][$x]; 
        $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x]; 

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$user_image_dir/{$username_entry}/{$name}"); 

        //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>'; 

        $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]); 
        $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]); 
        $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]); 
        $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]); 
        $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]); 

    }


    $insert_upload1 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload1"; 
    $insert_upload2 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload2"; 
    $insert_upload3 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload3"; 
    $insert_upload4 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload4"; 
    $insert_upload5 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload5"; 



    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 


    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO images (timestamp, username, password, business_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, email, website, Facebook, twitter, linkedin, opening_monday_from, opening_monday_to, opening_tuesday_from, opening_tuesday_to, opening_wednesday_from, opening_wednesday_to, opening_thursday_from, opening_friday_from, opening_friday_to, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_from, opening_saturday_to, opening_sunday_from, opening_sunday_to, business_type, business_description, managers_message, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5) VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['password_entry'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_name'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address1'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address2'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address3'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['postcode'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['website'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['facebook'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['twitter'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['linkedin'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_type'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_description'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['managers_message'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload1, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload2, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload3, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload4, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload5, "text")); 




    if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
        echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);


} else {

    die('no images given, so no insertion in DB');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

At the top of your script and give us the error.

Comment: Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/con.php on line 92

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/con.php on line 194

Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/con.php on line 129

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/con.php on line 195

Comment: Two problems : the directory seems to already exist, and mysql_select_db don't have correct parameters, so mysql_query don't work as expected.

Comment: Thats ok, as the directory will always be different due to unique username_entry. What do you suspect is going wrong with the parameters, i cant seem to find the issue.

Comment: added into original comment.I know this is me being an idiot, maybe im mixing up connection processes somehow?

Comment: Ok, you have a mix between mysql and mysqli function. You have to use only mysqli function because mysql function will be removed in next php versions.

Comment: can u suggest how to change this please, what to remove...thank you

Comment: Remove this line >> mysql_select_db($success, $insertSQL);
Change this line >>  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $link) or die(mysql_error());  } 

by mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error());  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73592/discussion-between-springheeled-jack-and-bigben3333).

Comment: Also you have two ?> tag at the end. You can remove them